# Why use Python PIP on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, pip

The Pip program is included by default with Python 3.4, and can also be installed on older versions. The aim is to provide a standard method of installing additional Python modules, which are available from the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)

For example, to add the PyOpenGL module, you can now just do this

```
pip install pyopengl
```

And Pip will take care of the rest. I can see that this would be very useful on systems other than Ubuntu-based ones. But I could just as easily do this

```
sudo apt-get install pyopengl
```

and the end result is the same.

So my question is, is there any reason to use Pip on Ubuntu at all, can I just stick with using Synaptic, or should I always be using Pip for Python packages (where they're available, not all are), or does it really not matter?

Comment: Thank you for that; I think both those posts provide me with enough information. Although I'm slightly annoyed with myself for failing to spot them while searching for similar questions.

Comment: They aren't easy to search. I had to go through my recent comments to get them. Your title is better, IMHO, so please don't delete it. Let it be closed as a dupe.